# Как включить Z-буфер (OpenGL 3.3)?

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml

Где предположительно может быть ошибка?
После создания окна (sf::RenderWindow) и контекста, перед главным циклом
отрисовки прописал

```cpp
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
```

в главном отрисовочном цикле

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

однако все равно буффер явно не подключен, дальние объекты залазят на ближние.

мин. пример:

```cpp
int main()
{
     sf::ContextSettings settings;
     settings.majorVersion = 3;
     settings.minorVersion = 3;

     sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 800), "nice", sf::Style::Default, settings);

     glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
     glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
     glDepthMask(GL_TRUE); // или glDepthFunc(GL_LESS) или просто ничего, разницы нет

    //VAO, VBO а также непосредственно массивы вершин и цветов

    while (window.isOpen())
     {
         glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
         //привязка буфферов, аттрибутов
         glDrawArryas(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 39);
         window.display();
     }

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: попробуйте включить `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);` и не указывайте явно `depthfunc` непосредственно перед `draw call`

Comment: [Минимальный пример, демонстрирующий проблему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) в студию.

Comment: Возможно при создании окна нужно явно выбирать точность z-буфера. Поищите в мануале к sfml, как это делается.

Comment: внимательнее, пожалуйста, GL_DEPTH_TEST "включен", а, несмотря на то, что depthfunc все равно должна работать, её наличие или её отсутствие ни на что не влияет.

Comment: @Dictator_zx внимательнее, пожалуйста, в сообщении должен был быть акцент на `непосредственно перед draw call`

Comment: внимательнее, пожалуйста, нет разницы указана перед draw call, в draw call или не указана вовсе

Comment: разница есть, именно поэтому я и предложил это проверить

Comment: можно добавить вершинный шейдер и проверить какие значения глубины получают объекты

Comment: попробуйте `settings.depthBits = 24;`

Comment: @Dictator_zx, если не читали, то почитайте, возможно поможет https://m.habr.com/ru/post/342610